# accessing phonegap database that was created

Tags: android, cordova

According to phonegap's API documentation,

> window.openDatabase returns a new Database object.
>
> This method will create a new SQL Lite Database and return a Database
>   object. Use the Database Object to manipulate the data.

However, what I dont understand is what happens when you close the app and reopen it. What happens to the database we created. Isnt it persisted and if so how to we retrieve it in order to perform other operations on it? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the database is persisted. All you need to do is provide the same "name" to window.openDatabase to open the database you have previously created.